# How can I make NppExec open a different file when clicking on console output?

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

I'm using Notepad++ and the NppExec plugin as a lightweight IDE for PHP.

I've added a console output filter for NppExec "%ABSFILE% on line %LINE%". When I get an error, I can double-click on it -- but it only navigates to the specified line in the currently active file. If the file with the error is on a different tab it does not switch tabs, nor does it open the file if it is not open.

How can I get NppExec to open the detected %ABSFILE% when I double-click?

I'm using Notepad++ 5.9.8 and NppExec 0.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I should have realized is that the NppExec console filter needs to match the entire line. For php parse errors, "%ABSFILE% on line %LINE%" is not sufficient, I needed "* in %ABSFILE% on line %LINE%".

Problem solved.